Firebase notification duplicated on ios when in foreground
Notification duplicate on ios when in foreground, but if i set the foreground alert to false i dont receive any notification at all but i get in the console log
await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
alert: false, ///if i set this to false i dont get notification at all when in foreground
badge: true,
sound: true,
);
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:io';

class NotificationService {
  static final NotificationService _instance = NotificationService._init();
  factory NotificationService() => _instance;

  NotificationService._init();

  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  bool _initialized = false;

  Future<String?> runFirebase() async {
    if (_initialized) {
      log("NotificationService is already initialized.");
      return null;
    }
    _initialized = true;

    log("Initializing NotificationService...");

    // Request notification permissions
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );

    // Get the FCM token
    String? fcmToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
    log("FCM Token: $fcmToken");

    // Initialization settings for Android
    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');

    // Initialization settings for iOS
    const DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS = DarwinInitializationSettings(
      requestAlertPermission: true,
      requestBadgePermission: true,
      requestSoundPermission: true,
    );

    // Combine initialization settings
    const InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
    );

    // Initialize the plugin
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (NotificationResponse response) {
        log("Notification Tapped");
        // Handle notification tap logic here
      },
    );

    // Set foreground notification presentation options
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );

    // Subscribe to a topic if needed
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic('all');
    log("Subscribed to topic 'all'");

    // Listen for foreground messages
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
      log("onMessage called: ${message.notification?.title ?? ''}");

      if (message.notification != null) {
        String? imageUrl = message.data['image'] ?? message.notification?.android?.imageUrl ?? message.notification?.apple?.imageUrl;

        if (imageUrl != null) {
          log("Image URL: $imageUrl");

          if (Platform.isAndroid) {
            // Image for Android
            final bigPicture = await _downloadAndSaveImage(imageUrl, 'bigPicture');
            final largeIcon = await _downloadAndSaveImage(imageUrl, 'largeIcon');

            if (bigPicture != null) {
              log("Displaying Android notification with image.");

              await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
                message.notification.hashCode,
                message.notification?.title ?? '',
                message.notification?.body ?? '',
                NotificationDetails(
                  android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                    'channelid',
                    'channelname',
                    channelDescription: 'channel description',
                    importance: Importance.high,
                    priority: Priority.high,
                    largeIcon: largeIcon != null ? FilePathAndroidBitmap(largeIcon) : null,
                    styleInformation: BigPictureStyleInformation(
                      FilePathAndroidBitmap(bigPicture),
                      largeIcon: largeIcon != null ? FilePathAndroidBitmap(largeIcon) : null,
                      contentTitle: message.notification?.title,
                      summaryText: message.notification?.body,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
          } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
            // Image for iOS
            final attachmentPath = await _downloadAndSaveImage(imageUrl, 'notification_image.jpg');

            if (attachmentPath != null) {
              log("Displaying iOS notification with image.");
              await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
                message.notification.hashCode,
                message.notification?.title ?? '',
                message.notification?.body ?? '',
                NotificationDetails(
                  iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails(
                    presentAlert: true,
                    presentBadge: true,
                    presentSound: true,
                    attachments: [
                      DarwinNotificationAttachment(
                        attachmentPath,
                        identifier: 'notification_image',
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
          }
        } else {
          // Handle notification without image
          log("Displaying standard notification without image.");

          NotificationDetails platformDetails;
          if (Platform.isAndroid) {
            platformDetails = const NotificationDetails(
              android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                'daiwa_food_notification',
                'daiwa_food_notification',
                channelDescription: 'Daiwa Food Channel',
                icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
                importance: Importance.high,
                priority: Priority.high,
              ),
            );
          } else {
            platformDetails = const NotificationDetails(
              iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails(
                presentAlert: true,
                presentBadge: true,
                presentSound: true,
              ),
            );
          }

          await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            message.notification.hashCode,
            message.notification?.title ?? '',
            message.notification?.body ?? '',
            platformDetails,
          );
        }
      }
    });

    // Listen for messages opened from background state
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      log("A message was opened from background state: ${message.messageId}");
      // Handle navigation or other logic here
    });

    // Handle messages when the app is opened from a terminated state
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((RemoteMessage? message) {
      if (message != null) {
        log("The app was opened from a terminated state by tapping on a notification.");
        // Handle navigation or other logic here
      }
    });

    return fcmToken;
  }

  Future<String?> _downloadAndSaveImage(String url, String fileName) async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
        final filePath = '${directory.path}/$fileName';
        final file = File(filePath);
        await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
        log("Image saved to $filePath");
        return filePath;
      } else {
        log("Failed to download image. Status code: ${response.statusCode}");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      log("Failed to download image: $e");
    }
    return null;
  }
}


Expecting to only received 1 notification when in foreground. works on android

foreground notifications are handled automatically by the firebase messaging plugin. So on the onMessage function, you don't need to use flutterLocalNotification plugin to show the notification.
Since firebase messaging handles the notification, and the flutterLocalNotification plugin is also showing a notification, you will get two notifications in the notification tray.

https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/13366
apparently its a bug in ios 18.
